# Do different castes have different Karmic outcomes for the same action?

Tags: karma, manu-smriti

The differential treatments of different castes that Manu et al prescribe are for earthly punishments/rewards for earthly actions.

Does any scripture says that for the exactly same Papa or Punya, a Sudra would have a different Karmic outcome than a Brahmin?

Comment: all these recent questions about karma, manu smriti, vedas are related, you can group them into one.

Answer (score 2):

> Do different castes have different Karmic outcomes for the same action?

**Yes, different actions produce different karmic fruit for different people, because the Dharma for castes are different.**

For example, it is a huge sin for Brahmins to eat onions and garlic, whereas there is no sin for Shudras:

> **[Manu 5.5](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200379.html)** - Garlic, leeks and onions, mushrooms and all that proceeds from impure things, are unfit to be eaten by twice-born men.
>
> **[Manu 5.19](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200394.html)** - The mushroom, the village-pig, garlic, the village-cock, onions and leeks,—**the twice-born man eating these intentionally would become an outcast.**
>
> ‘Na pātakam’—‘no sin [for the Shudra], in eating garlic and other forbidden vegetables and fruits’ (Govindarāja and Kullūka),—‘in keeping a slaughter-house’ (Rāghavānanda).

[Chapter 3](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/3) of the Bhagavad Gita says that it's better to do one's own Dharma than another's:

> It is far better to discharge one’s prescribed duties, even though
> faultily, than another’s duties perfectly. Destruction in the course
> of performing one’s own duty is better than engaging in another’s
> duties, for to follow another’s path is dangerous.

Brahmanas who engage in trade practice medicine are to be despised (fallen off from Brahmanhood), whereas trade and business is a required duty for Vaishyas:

> **[8.102](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201008.html)** - ‘He shall treat like Śūdras the Brāhmaṇas who tend cattle, who engage in trade, and who are craftsmen, actors, menial servants or money-lenders.’
>
> (Brâhmanas) who neither study nor teach the Veda nor keep sacred fires become equal to Sûdras;
>
> And they quote a verse of Manu on this (subject), 'A twice-born man, who not having studied the Veda applies himself to other (worldly studies), soon falls, even while living, to the condition of a Sûdra, and his descendants after him.'
>
> '(A twice-born man) who does not know the Veda (can)not be (called) a Brâhmana, nor he who lives by trade, nor he who (lives as) an actor, nor he who obeys a Sûdra's commands, nor (he who like) a thief (takes the property of others), **nor he who makes his living by the practice of medicine.'**
>
> **[9.326](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201719.html)** - After having his sacraments performed, the Vaiśya shall take a wife and apply himself entirely to agriculture and the tending of catlle.
>
> **[9.328](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201721.html)** - The Vaiśya shall never conceive the wish—‘I will not tend cattle;’ and so long as the Vaiśya is willing, they should not be tended by any one else.
>
> **[9.331](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201724.html)** - Also the excellences and defects of commodities, the advantages and disadvantages relating to countries, the profit and loss on merchandise and also cattle-breeding.
>
> Yājñavalkya (Parāśaramādhava-Ācāra, p. 416).—‘Money-lending, agriculture, trade, and cattle-tending have been ordained for the Vaiśya.’

And many more actions such as drinking alcohol, pronouncing the Vedas, etc.

From the *[Garuda Purana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/gpu/gpu06.htm)*:

> The Brāhmiṇ who sells liquors, and consorts with a lowcaste woman; who
> kills animals for his own gratification, not for the prescribed
> sacrifices of the Vedas;
>
> Who has put aside his Brāhmaṇic duties; who eats flesh and drinks
> liquor; who is of unbridled nature; who does not study the Śāstras;
>
> The Śūdra who studies the letter of the Vedas, who drinks the milk of
> the tawny cow, who wears the sacred thread or consorts with Brāhmiṇ
> women;
>
> Who covets the King's wife; who abducts others' wives, who is lustful
> towards virgins, and who slanders virtuous women;--
>
> **These, and many other fools, fond of treading forbidden paths, anal abandoning prescribed duties, fall into the Vaitaraṇī [river, which
> borders Hell].**